# Is memory being freed when calling exec(3) an implementation detail?

Tags: c, memory, exec, posix, heap-memory

From what I've read, the general consensus seems to be that you don't need to free memory before running `exec(3)`. However, in the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exec.html), handling of the heap / malloc memory does not seem to be explicitly detailed. I know it's common for people to not bother freeing memory when an application is exiting because the OS will clean up the data, but from what I understand, that's an OS implementation detail; the OS is not **required** to free the memory even though many modern systems do. Is this also the case with `exec(3)`? I'm wondering if freeing `malloc`'d memory before `exec(3)` is the right thing to do even though it's not necessary for many modern operating systems.

Comment: Freeing malloced memory is *always* the right thing to do.

Comment: exec := posix := unix. So this is not a C question but a unix/posix question. And since exec *replaces* the calling program by the new program, the address space of the old program can (*will*) be disrupted. [see also: fork/vfork discussions]

Comment: Some languages that provide a FFI or wrapper around exec do some internal accounting / memory management before ultimately calling the POSIX function. C doesn't (as far as I know), and C is the language I care about for the context of this question.

Comment: @KerrekSB Rephrased: Freeing malloced memory *when you're done using it* is *never a wrong thing* to do. (It may be redundant, in which case it's neither right nor wrong)

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not an implementation detail. The freeing of memory is implicit in the definition of the [`exec`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execv.html) function family:

> The exec family of functions shall replace the current process image with a new process image.

The POSIX standard doesn't appear to have a clear definition of "process image", but from context, it's pretty clear that this includes all aspects of process state, including memory allocations.

From a practical standpoint, any system where memory left allocated at `exec` time was *not* deallocated would be essentially unusable, as those memory allocations would become unreachable.

Comment: The specification does cover a lot of things that are released, including various memory mappings.  There's a list of what's preserved too; it doesn't include memory (not even shared memory — which is perfectly reasonable when you think about it a bit).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The spec states "Memory mappings created in the process are unmapped before the address space is rebuilt for the new process image." Does "memory mappings" refer to memory allocated with mmap, or does it mean something else? On Linux, glibc malloc seems to be implemented in terms of mmap, but the POSIX page for malloc does not list this as a requirement. Based on that, it sounds like the memory allocated by malloc is only required to be freed if malloc is implemented in terms of mmap.